# transform rows into one row based on unique ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Reason                       |   ID
---------------------------------------
Sales - Agent Attitude       |    2
---------------------------------------
Billing - Process            |    2
---------------------------------------
Technical -  Outages         |   1005
---------------------------------------
Technical -  knowledge       |   1005
---------------------------------------
Others                       |   1005
---------------------------------------
```

i have the above table and i want a result like the below by using SQL server i can combine rows into one row by separating them by , by using STUFF() function but i want the format as the below so any help

```
   ID   | Reason 1               | Reason 2                  | Reason 3
   ---------------------------------------------------------------------
   2    | Sales - Agent Attitude | Billing - Process         | NULL
   ---------------------------------------------------------------------
  1005  | Technical -  Outages   | Technical -  knowledge    |Others
   ---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: What's the expected result if an ID has 4 different reasons?

Comment: Read about [pivot.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: @jarlh i will customize the code with max reasons i will have

Comment: @ZoharPeled i tried pivot but still result is not appear at one single row

Answer (score 0):

Try below query..

```
            select distinct  
            ID   , [1] as 'Reason 1' , [2] as 'Reason 2' , [3] as 'Reason 3'
            from
            (
              select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION  BY id ORDER BY reason DESC ) as RID from #temp
            ) src
            pivot
            (
              max(Reason)
              for rid in ([1], [2],[3])
            ) piv
```

plz let us know if you have any que. or concerns

Comment: thanks @Mr. Bhosale  but ID still duplicate each one with a reason and other reasons null i need to combine all result at one row

Comment: can you add more duplicate o/p

Answer (score 0):

This is the pivot solution:

```
;with
t as (
    SELECT 'Reason ' + cast(ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by id order by id) as varchar(2)) n, *
    from YourTable
)
select *
FROM t
pivot (min(reason) for n in ([Reason 1],[Reason 2],[Reason 3],[Reason 4],[Reason 5])) p
```

Comment: ID also still duplicate each one with a reason and other reasons null i need to combine all result at one row